# DataVisualization set transparency of area

Tags: c#, transparency

I have a series:

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Area
```

How do I make the area transparent so I can see other previously plotted series?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hav you tried [ChartArea.BackColor Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartarea.backcolor.aspx)

> You can set this property to any valid ARGB (alpha, red, green, blue)
>   value.
>
> The BackColor value will be the first color used if you have specified
>   gradient colors for the background.
>
> **The alpha value controls the opacity of a color. If you set this color to "transparent"—that is, if you use an alpha value of 0—no
>   color will be assigned to the background of the chart area. As a
>   result, the background will be transparent.**

Comment: I didn't try it because it is the "area" under the line that I want transparent - not the background of the chart....

Comment: ARGB (alpha, red, green, blue) also works on the color of the           line/area itself - not just the background.

Answer (score 3):

```
SeriesA.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Area;
SeriesA.Color = Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Yellow);
```

alpha's range is from 0-255